# How can I check if a node already exist, before linking it to a new node in Neo4j with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, nodes

I'm novice in Neo4j and cypher and would like some help solving an issue. All help would be appreciated.

This is my problem:

I have created two nodes, one as a user and one as a city, linked to the user.

Graph setup

```
CREATE (n:User{firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe"});

MATCH (user:User{firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe"})
Return user;
```

Query:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE user.firstName = "John"
CREATE (city:City { cityName:"Liverpool", areaCode:"34343" })
CREATE (user)-[:STUDY_IN]->(city);
```

Now I want to create a new node(user) and link that user to the existing node (city:Liverpool).

I've done that i this way:

```
MATCH (city:City)
WHERE city.cityName = "Liverpool"
CREATE (user:User { firstName : "Kent", lastName : "Clark" })
CREATE (user)-[:STUDY_IN]->(city);
```

In real life, I would need to check if the city exist, before creating the relationship and if it doesn't exist, then I would like to create a new node for that city.

You can see my code here:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=utor92

Comment: Have you seen the `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE` clauses for Cypher `MERGE`? http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MERGE` command which will match a pattern if it exists or create it if it doesn't.

```
CREATE (user:User{firstName: "Kent", lastName: "Clark"})
MERGE (city:City{cityName: "Liverpool"})
CREATE (user)-[:STUDY_IN]->(city)
RETURN user, city
```

You can also use `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` with `MERGE`. For example:

```
MERGE (city:City{cityName: "Manchester"})
ON CREATE SET city.foo = "bar"
ON MATCH SET city.baz = "qux"
```

In this example if `city` does not exist it will be created and the property `foo` is set to `"bar"`. If it exists already the property `baz` gets set to `"qux"`.

For a more in depth look at `MERGE` [check out the docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html).

Comment: I used the first suggestion and it solved my problem. Thx @stephenmuss